# Visual Studio 2015 Curly Brace Formatting: If, Else If, Else

Tags: c#, formatting, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 (update 1) and have been getting things configured as I want them to be, however I am having a little trouble with formatting with regards to curly braces! I am under the assumption that the 2nd code sample is the more accepted convention, yet I can not seem to get my settings right. What am I doing wrong here?

Visual Studio is currently auto-formatting my code like this, notice the **else {**

```
    public static string Gender(string x)
    {
        if (x == "M")
        {
            return "Male";
        }
        else if (x == "F")
        {
            return "Female";
        }
        else {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

I would like my code to be auto-formatted like this

```
    public static string Gender(string x)
    {
        if (x == "M")
        {
            return "Male";
        }
        else if (x == "F")
        {
            return "Female";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines > [Enable] Place open brace on new line for control blocks. i think this should work.

Comment: This seems to be broken in VS2015 update 1. It doesn't seem to care which line the `{` following the `else` is on, and won't auto-format it with either of the above styles (given default settings). Doesn't seem to operate the same way as VS2012 at least, which is the only comparison point I have available.

Comment: resharper will fix this. while giving you a lot of useful features to write your code faster. when i installed VS 2015 first thing i did was to install resharper! so i didnt notice this problem ;) https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: I hope they fix this soon because it drives me CRAZY!!!

Comment: I was seeking a solution for this, then I found your question here. Did you find a solution for this yet? Thank you.

Comment: This is fixed in Update 2

Answer (score 3):

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and have it set up to format like in your second code snippet.

An important setting is to **un**check "place else on new line" option.

If this is not enough, I am posting a screenshot with all my settings (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdzTZ.jpg)

[image]